# preg_replace spaces between the last 4 digits

Tags: php, preg-replace

I know how to remove spaces from a string:

`$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $text);`

But what if I need to remove spaces ONLY between 4 last digits of ANY number?

As an example:

`12895 6 7 8 9` - I want it to become `12895 6789`

or

`2546734 34 55` - I want it to become `2546734 3455`

or

`2334734556 341 5` - I want it to become `2334734556 3415`

How do I do that?

** Update: I want to remove spaces between the last four digits not after the first space (since all examples show the space). So something like that would be a better example:

`23347345563 4 1 5` - I want it to become `23347345563415`

Comment: Remove spaces between last four, or after first space?

Comment: Or, what if you remove all spaces and insert a space just before the last four

Comment: @TimMorton remove spaces between last four. I will update my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with `preg_replace` and this regular expression:

```
\s+(?=(\d\s*){0,3}$)
```

which looks for a space followed by 0 to 3 digits (with optional spaces) between it and the end of the line (using a positive lookahead). Simply replace those spaces with an empty string (`''`):

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s+(?=(\d\s*){0,3}$)/', '', '12895 6 7 8 9');
echo "$text\n";
$text = preg_replace('/\s+(?=(\d\s*){0,3}$)/', '', '2546734 34 55');
echo "$text\n";
$text = preg_replace('/\s+(?=(\d\s*){0,3}$)/', '', '2334734556 341 5');
echo "$text\n";
$text = preg_replace('/\s+(?=(\d\s*){0,3}$)/', '', '23347345563 4 1 5');
echo "$text\n";
```

Output:

```
12895 6789
2546734 3455
2334734556 3415
23347345563415
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BaGJZ)

Comment: Yes sir! Thank you. Works for all (any length) numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function func($text, $digits = 4){
  $str = '';
  for ($i = strlen($text)-1; $i >= 0; $i--){
    if(strlen($str) < $digits && !is_numeric($text[$i]))continue;
    $str .= $text[$i];
  }
  return strrev($str);
}

$text1 = '12895 6 7 8 9';
$text2 = '2546734 34 55';
$text3 = '2334734556 341 5';


echo func($text1, 4);   //12895 6789
echo func($text2, 4);   //2546734 3455
echo func($text3, 4);   //2334734556 3415
```

Comment: I am not getting it. I am not sure how to apply `$text1 = '12895 6 7 8 9';
$text2 = '2546734 34 55';
$text3 = '2334734556 341 5';` My outcome should be `$text`. Can I just use `$text`?

Comment: Yes, `$text = func($text, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that uses regex, have a look at the example below. It uses a match to get the different parts of the string, then concatenates it back in the correct format.

```php
$strings = [
    '12895 6 7 8 9',
    '2546734 34 55',
    '2334734556 341 5',
];

function formatNumber($number)
{
    preg_match('/(\d+) ?((?:[\d]\s*){4})$/', $number, $matches);

    if (!$matches) {
        return $number;
    }

    return sprintf('%s %s', $matches[1], str_replace(' ', '', $matches[2]));
}

var_dump(array_map('formatNumber', $strings));
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(10) "12895 6789"
  [1] =>
  string(12) "2546734 3455"
  [2] =>
  string(15) "2334734556 3415"
}
```